Identifying α-hydrogen atoms with respect to tautomerism and enolization
If we have to identify α-hydrogen atoms with regards to tautomerism, do we consider all the hydrogen atoms attached to the α-carbon, including the hydrogen atom attached to a $\text{sp}^2$-carbon which cannot be enolised?
Or do we only consider the hydrogen atoms which are enolisable and attached to the α-carbon, i.e. only those hydrogens which are attached to the $\text{sp}^3$-carbon and can be enolised?

There is no point in including $\alpha$-hydrogen atoms attached to $\text{sp}^2$ or $\text{sp}$ hybridised carbon atoms while counting the number of $\alpha$-hydrogen atoms as these cannot participate in tautomerism as you have stated. This is due to high bond angle, i.e., $120^\circ$ in $\text{sp}^2$ and $180^\circ$ in $\text{sp}$ compared to $109^\circ28’$ in $\text{sp}^3$. So, only those $\alpha$-hydrogen atoms that are attached to $\text{sp}^3$ hybridised carbon atoms are considered in tautomerism and enolization.
P.S. the same applies to identifying $\alpha$-hydrogen atoms in hyperconjugation.

Oh thank you I now get it . So  I'm assuming the same logic would be followed in identifying alpha carbon as well?  That is it must have enolisable hydrogen attached to it ( in context of enolization and tautomerism)?

@Bharat no, an $\alpha$-carbon atom w.r.t. a functional group is a carbon atom directly attached to it. The same applies to atoms of any other element, since the prefix $\alpha$ is used to indicate this. In your question, all hydrogen atoms attached to $\alpha$-C are $\alpha$-H, but only those attached to an $\text{sp}^3$-C atom will participate in tautomerism. H-atoms directly attached to $\text{sp}^2$ or $\text{sp}$ C atoms are also $\alpha$-H, but these will not participate in tautomerism.

Oh so basically all the carbon atoms  directly attached to a functional grp are alpha-C and their hydrogen would be alpha- H. And depending upon  hybridization of C atom it's hydrogen( alpha-H) may or may not participate in enolization

@Bharat yes, you are correct.

@Bharat kindly consider upvoting and accepting my answer if you find it helpful.
